# OpenCV getRectSubPix with Alpha Channel

Tags: opencv, alpha, roi

I need to use the getRectSubPix function in my code as part of a process of cropping an rotating a section of my image. This works fine normally with 3 channel images, but as soon as I try to use it with a BGRA or a RGBA mat image it crashes saying to me

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats () in cvGetRectSubPix, file /home/biotracking/Downloads/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/imgproc/src/samplers.cpp, line 550

my code is basically like this

```
                cv::cvtColor(polymask, polymask, CV_BGR2BGRA);
                getRectSubPix(polymask, cv::Size(sqrt(biggestdistancesquared)*2,sqrt(biggestdistancesquared)*2), src_center, polymask);
```

If this function truly didn't work for Mats with alpha channels that seems crazy. Anybody know?

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this problem and the answer by @blorgggg a while ago, and doubted deeply, since the problem is related with **channels**, but the answer is related with **depth**.

---

My answer: 
The error rises because `getRectSubPix` supports only image of channels 1 or 3.

Related Code:

```
if( (cn != 1 && cn != 3) || !CV_ARE_CNS_EQ( src, dst ))
    CV_Error( CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "" );
```

---

The statement in thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362483/open-cv-using-16-bit-signed-format-not-working-cropping-and-re-sizing-an-imag) by @luhb is true, since it indeed supports only image of depth 8 or 32 is true, but has nothing to do with the question here.

Related code:

```
if( CV_MAT_DEPTH( src->type ) != CV_8U || CV_MAT_DEPTH( dst->type ) != CV_32F )
            CV_Error( CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "" );
```

**I check the code snippet in version 2.4/2.8/2.9.**

---

Finally, to solve your trouble, you could first split the Mat, `getRectSuxPix` on each channel, and then merge the four channels.

Answer (score 0):

Another guy nailed the answer to this question
in this other question user luhb answered: [Open CV using 16 bit signed format not working... Cropping and re-sizing an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362483/open-cv-using-16-bit-signed-format-not-working-cropping-and-re-sizing-an-imag)

It seems getRectSubPix only work with {src,dst} type of {CV_8U, CV_8U}, {CV_32F, CV_32F} and {CV_8U, CV_32F}.

I dip into the source code and figure that out. There's no specification in the API reference.